# Kohana underscore in directory name

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I inherited a rather large application using Kohana v3. There are directories with the name "_view" and filenames that begin with _(underscore). Does Kohana do something magical with these files and directories? A good reference would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

In kohana there are four different file types where underscore will be translated into `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`: [classes](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files/classes), [config](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files/config), [translation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files/i18n), [message](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files/messages). This rules will be applied with autoloader only, e.g. `$user = new Model_User()` loads the `/classes/model/user.php`. But you can use the underscore with `Kohana::find_file()`. Please take a closer look to the Kohana's [Cascading filesystem](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files).

In two words: if those files located outside the `[application|module|system]/classes`, `[application|module|system]/views`, `[application|module|system]/messages`, `[application|module|system]/i18n` and not defined additional autoloaders in the `bootstrap.php` or `index.php` they does not have any magical things.